# Why not working "platform_fees" in PayPal API?

Tags: api, paypal, marketplace

Why is it that when I send funds, the money goes to only one account, and no commission is sent to the second account? All accounts are set up, no restrictions, everything needed is there.

My request:

```
request.post(PAYPAL_API + '/v2/checkout/orders', {
        auth: {
            user: CLIENT,
            pass: SECRET
        },
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: {
            "intent": "CAPTURE",
            "purchase_units": [{
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": "1.00"
                },
                "payee": {
                    "email_address": "seller account"
                },
                "description": "Item 1",
                "payment_instruction": {
                    "disbursement_mode": "INSTANT",
                    "platform_fees": [{
                        "amount": {
                            "currency_code": "USD",
                            "value": "0.25"
                        },
                        "payee": {
                            "email_address": "fee account"
                        },
                    }]
                }
            }],
        },
        json: true
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you (the API caller's clientID) a PayPal partner?

[PayPal Commerce Platform](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/) features and parameters such as `platform_fees` are only available to approved PayPal partners ... and would apparently just be ignored otherwise.

There is a form linked here where you can contact PayPal about being a partner: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/onboarding/partner-onboarding/ (If you do not receive a reply, unfortunately that would most likely be because your business does not qualify at this time.)